# T-SQL : Can you concatenate query results from a loop into a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

So I have this query right here:

```
OPEN @getid


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @table, @funckey



    set @query = '


    select '''+@table+''' as Tab,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_NAME= '''+@table+''') as Columns,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) Lines
    FROM '+@table+') as Lines
    '
    EXEC sp_executesql @query 
    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @getid INTO @table, @funckey

END
```

So I'm trying to get the name, number of columns and number of lines for each database table into a same resulting table, but this method returns one result table by iteration. So I'm wondering how I can concatenate the lines instead of having each one be in its own table.

Is there any way to have all the itérations aliment the same table ?
(i left out some of the variable declaration lines for more clarity)

Comment: Why are you using a cursor? You can do this with a single query...

Comment: What are you actually trying to archieve here? This doesn't seem like you need a `CURSOR`, no. Also, your `WHILE` is flawed, as you retreive the first data row, and then discard it in the first iteration of the `WHILE` before processing it.

Comment: @larnu You're right, I moved the "FETCH NEXT FROM..." bit after the query execution. What do you thing is the right way to do this task ?

Comment: *"What do you thing is the right way to do this task ?"* i don't know, I don't know what you're actually trying to achieve here; that's why i asked.

Comment: @larnu So I'm trying to get the name, number of columns and number of lines for each database table into a same resulting table, but this method returns one result table by iteration. So I'm wondering how I can concatenate the lines instead of having each one be in its own table.

Comment: That should 8really* be in yoru question, @Nossair .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question lacks information on why the SQL they have provided does not provide them the answer they want. From the comments on the question, and in my answer, the requirements have also changed multiple times, meaning that the real goal is unclear without clear requirements, details of why the SQL provided doesn't work, and clearly defined expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If my reading of this comment is correct:

> I'm trying to get the name, number of columns and number of lines for each database table into a same resulting table, but this method returns one result table by iteration. So I'm wondering how I can concatenate the lines instead of having each one be in its own table.

It seems like you don't need a `CURSOR` at all, if you're happy with a "good" estimate for the row count.

```
SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
       t.name AS TableName,
       c.Columns,
       p.Rows
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Columns
                  FROM sys.columns c
                  WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id) c
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows
                  FROM sys.partitions p
                  WHERE p.object_id = t.object_id
                    AND p.index_id IN (0,1)) p;
```

Comment: I was using the cursor because, the code in my post only being a sample of the whole thing in an effort to keep the purpose clear, the query also includes counting the number of duplicates in each table, and the number of missing lines from the source table in another database, which is why I couldn't just rely on the Sys data. But thanks for the answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Nossair it's not counting the distinct rows, it's counting the distinct columns in your table, which makes little sense, as you can't have 2 columns with the same name in a table.

Comment: You also don't say you want the distinct rows in your comment (which should be in your question), @Nossair : *"I'm trying to get the name, number of columns and number of lines for each database table"* Where does that mention "unique rows"? How would you determine what a "unique row" is? If that is the case, sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) as why would you have 2 rows that are identical in a table in the first place?

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for the confusion I'm still learning question-asking etiquette on here to maximize the chances of finding an answer, thanks for that link.

Comment: Also, the cursor fetches the name and the functional key of the table (which I gathered in a CTE), so a unique line is defined by its functional key. Tho that's not really a problem here since it works just fine. The issue is managing to gather the data into a single table.

Comment: You *keep* changing/moving the requirements here, @Nossair . You need to edit your question as there is no clear problem any more.